# Inserting rows using cx_Oracle and logging the ones that fail?

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle

What I am trying to do is insert a bunch of rows using cx_Oracle and if there is an error (i.e. constraint violation) log the bad row.

Here is the sudo code for how I would do it using execute, however this doesn't seem very efficient.

```
for row in rows:
    try:
        cursor.execute("sql", row)
    except InsertError:
        badRecordCSVFile.write(row)
```

I read the [docs](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/html/cursor.html) and at first it seemed like [executemany](http://cx-oracle.sourceforge.net/html/cursor.html#Cursor.executemany) was what I was looking for. However, after reading this [thread](http://en.usenet.digipedia.org/thread/15912/2704/) it would seem that executemany simply processes queries until it fails (not what I want).

So my question is what is the best way to insert rows and log the ones that fail?

Comment: [DML error logging](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=329) may help.

Comment: Use the batcherrors feature: https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/BatchErrors.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SQL parameters for the insertion statement, this is efficient enough; the bottleneck will be in the network communication with Oracle.

By using SQL parameters, Oracle is given a chance to prepare a query plan, then reuse it on each and every insert.

If you plan to roll back the transaction when an insertion fails, however, you may as well use `.executemany()`.

Comment: by SQL parameters you mean `INSERT INTO myTable (col1, col2) VALUES (:val1 :val2)`?

Comment: @johnthexiii: Yes, exactly.